# auto-summarization: classful vs classless routing protocols

Tags: ip-routing, rip

Suppose a router R1 is directly connected to the following subnets:

10.1.0.0/24

10.1.1.0/24

10.1.2.0/24

10.1.3.0/24

If it is running RIPv1, it will advertise:

"i have the network 10.0.0.0" (implicitly understood by receiving RIPv1 routers as 10.0.0.0/8 because the protocol is classful)

but suppose we changed the routing protocol to RIPv2 and turned ON auto-summarization.
Would it behave in the same way? Would it advertise:

"i have the network 10.0.0.0" (advertised WITHOUT subnet mask, and implicitly understood by other routers as 10.0.0.0/8)

OR would it auto-summarize in a non classful way like:

"i have 10.1.0.0/22" (advertised as network id and subnet mask pair)

In other words, does turning on auto-summarization in RIPv2 (or other classless routing protocols) cause it to auto-summarize in a classful manner or simply auto-summarize classlessly to the best of its ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on the router, but if you do not define a subnet (if the router allows this) than it would be logical to advertise the class. However if you define the subnetmask it will advertise the subnet.

Comment: That is my understanding as well. It totally depends on the routers firmware. It may even make a difference if you setup these routes straigth in RIPv2 or if you set them up in RIPv1 and then migrate to v2. (v1 may have implicitly stored them as class A which migrates into a /8 in v2 when you upgrade.) This is very implementation depended

Comment: From my experience with cisco routers, you cannot give a layer 3 interface an IP address without giving a subnet mask as well, so assume the router always knows the subnet it is attached to. Then question is: how does the router summarize its attached subnets when RIPv2 auto-summarization is on, classfully or classlessly? (I dont think it should depend on the router since we are referring to the behavior of a standardized routing protocol).

Comment: auto-summarize will summarize them classfull IIRC

Comment: Classfull would be logical I presume if you upgrade from v1 to v2 and then turn of auto-summary as the OP asks. That would maintain the state of the configuration, so there is no change in behavior of the network as a whole.